# Creating custom or repeated transition effects in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

Let's say I want to create a video with a large number of fairly complex transitions --- for the sake of argument, let's consider an old-fashioned carousel project slideshow. On each transition, the image needs to be moved off to the left, with the new image moved on from the right.

Setting this up *once* isn't too bad; I spend a few minutes fiddling with the keyframes and curves, and it's done. But now I have 150 more images to apply the same effect to. What's worse, once I render and send it off to my boss they're likely to send it back to me telling me to speed up every transition by 5%.

What I'd really like to do is to create a custom effect strip which applies the effect; then whenever I want my effect I simply overlap two images and apply the custom transition. Crucially, I would then be able to *edit* the transition strip to change the timings throughout the video.

Is such a thing possible, and if so, how?

Things I've looked at:

- I've looked at metastrips, but I don't think they're usable as effects. Plus, I don't think I can create a linked duplicate (Alt+D doesn't appear to work in the VSE), so I'd still need to go through and edit each one manually to adjust the timings.
- I know about mask effects, which look great, but they can only overlay one strip on another, and can't apply effects like translations or scales.